# How do i create a new array with new properties from an existing array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, ecmascript-6, lambda

I am trying to create a new list from an existing list `messages`. for a partically reason the reason i am doing this is to be able to pass this new list into a react component, and that react component is expecting an object that has the value of `id` and `name`, and not what the properties of the existing list are (messageId, and messageName)

I have tried the below amount however the below does not work and i get expected Expression statement is not an assignment or call.

```
const newItems = []
    newItems.push(messages.map(message => {
        id: message.messageId;
        name: message.messageName
    }))
```

Comment: you don't need to use .push here. When you use methods like `.map()`, `.reduce()`, `.filter()`, what all these have in common is that they don't modify your current array, they always create a new one for you. You can do a `console.log()` of your messages array after you used the `.map()` method and you will notice that the array remains unchanged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are these issues:

- When using the arrow function syntax, the opening brace of (what you intend to be) the object literal is interpreted as the start of a statement block. To avoid this, wrap the literal in parentheses.
- In an object literal the properties should not be separated by semicolon, but by colon
- `.map` returns the array, so if you push that array to `newItems`, the latter will have just one entry: an array. Instead you just need the returned array to be assigned to `newItems` -- without `push`

So:

```js
const messages = [{messageId: 1, messageName: "Hello"},{messageId: 2, messageName: "World"}];

const newItems = messages.map(message => ({
    id: message.messageId,
    name: message.messageName
}));

console.log(newItems);
```